# Creating Tab Bar using fragments from support package

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Hello I am searching a good example creating my custom Tab Bar (at the bottom) using fragments.

Earlier I had written this using Activities Groups, but from android 3.* it's deprecated and I need to do this using fragments.

Here is the code I had written creating my custom Tab Bar:

```
private void setTabs()
{

    //Implementing strings
    String publication = String.format("First");
    String shop = String.format("Second");

    //Adding tabs to TabActivity
    //addTab(publication, R.drawable.ic_launcher, DisplayTestActivity.class);
   //addTab(shop, R.drawable.ic_launcher, DisplayPushedTestActivity.class);



}


@Override
public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

/**
 * 
 * @param labelId, tab name
 * @param drawableId, tab icon image
 * @param c, responsible class
 */
/*
private void addTab(String labelId, int drawableId, Class<?> c)
{
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, c);

    TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab" + labelId); 


    View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, getTabWidget(), false);

    System.out.println(tabIndicator);

    TextView title = (TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.tab_bar_title);

    System.out.println(labelId);
    System.out.println(title);
    title.setText(labelId);
    ImageView icon = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.tab_bar_icon);
    icon.setImageResource(drawableId);

    spec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
    spec.setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
}
```

Maybe someone could share some info about this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The developer website has a bunch of examples on how to do this. See [`FragmentTabs.java`](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentTabs.html), as well as the [**API 4+ Support Demos**](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/index.html) page.

This is a nice [**tutorial**](http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/04/android-tabs-the-fragment-way/) too if you need a step-by-step.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to integrate [Actionbarsherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) into your project. It enables you to use the new TabApi from Honeycomb and Ice Cream Sandwich in all versions down to Android 2.x. It makes adding tabs really easy and your app will follow the Android Design Guidelines and really look like an Android App.